# **Save Image with added mask in python**

Tags: python, image-processing, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to save an image on which I added a white mask on all the interest areas. But for some reason, It doesn't save the final image and it's not returning any error message. How can I save my image with the mask?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Desktop/testim.png') 
gray_scale = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
# Set threshold level 

Dark = 10 

coords = np.column_stack(np.where(gray_scale < Dark)) 

print("xy:\n", coords)

mask = gray_scale < Dark

# Color the pixels in the mask 

image[mask] = (255, 255, 255) 

cv2.imshow('mask', image) 
cv2.waitKey()

#save new image with the added mask to directory 
if not cv2.imwrite(r'./mask.png', image):
     raise Exception("Could not write image")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it relates to several typos in the program. After fixing them everything works quite nicely.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


image = cv2.imread('/content/test.png') 
gray_scale = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
# Set threshold level 

Dark = 10 

coords = np.column_stack(np.where(gray_scale < Dark)) 

# print("xy:\n", coords)

mask = gray_scale < Dark

# Color the pixels in the mask 

image[mask] = (255, 255, 255) 
# cv2.imshow('mask', image) 
cv2.waitKey()

if not cv2.imwrite(r'./mask.png', image):
     raise Exception("Could not write image")
```

image before manipulation[image]

image after manipulation[image]

Comment: My mistake on the code, but I was able to do what you just did. My question was how to save the image after I added the white mask. Where were you able to save yours?

Comment: I see, the command `cv2.imwrite(r'./mask.png', image)` stores `image` object in the current directory with the name `mask.png` @aprilW

Comment: I did that but it did not store the image containing the mask in the directory